# Sharepoint 2013 advices on slideshow app type

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, app

I developed a full Web Slideshow, via Nappa (online development tools), connected to a SharePoint list. It works well on the Sharepoint online test server but now I want to make it works on our local SharePoint site.

**initial app** :
I used JQuery, CSS and HTML markup to make the slideshow part and Javascript CSOM to get the informations (picture url, titles, description, etc ...) from a Sharepoint list.

**app I tried to do** :
For my test on local server, I used a Visual Studio 2012 and I tried to make it works with a Low-Trust App part provider-hosted. (got an app and appweb project in my VS solution, and trying basically to create a view on my app from my app web).

**The question** :
I would like advices from people who faced the same issue as mine : the web is full of differents example, and I don't know where to head to build a simple app that I could add in any page of my SharePoint site (like a Webpart). Because a default app is executed in a different context, and different domain, and it can't be integrated in a SharePoint page.

If i'm not clear enough I would like to do something like that : 
[image: Schema architecture]

So, please, can you tell me what kind of app to do, where the code should be hosted, ... ? Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question : I compared, read tutorials, and clarified my vision of the SP apps. For my needs, the easier and better to do seems to be a low-trust App SharePoint-hosted. Added it a ClientWebPart component and make it point on the .aspx page containing my Slideshow.

I got it to work by recreating a clean project and followed these 2 tutorials :
http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2012/08/01/how-to-build-a-sharepoint-hosted-client-web-part-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx

http://jeffreypaarhuis.com/2013/03/22/how-to-create-an-app-part-in-sharepoint-2013/

I've got confused at the first glance, because there were a lot of different methods, and trying those one by one, accumulating errors and dump-code/files ran me crazy.
So an advice to whoever wants to learn how to make SharePoint apps :

- Don't hesitate to make several starts from scratch
- Carefully and methodically apply your modifications
- Take your time to read some about the subject

You can quickly be drowned.